# What type of lock used by xDocument.load method at time of loading xml file?

Tags: wpf, xml, vb.net, wcf, linq

I'm having application in VB.net which is using LINQ and try to save data on local machine which reduce performance.

What I believe is that because of the sync. application constantly write data on xml file which is accessible by local machine, locked at time of load and released at time of save!!!!! not sure about that.

I'm using:

```
Dim xdocSetting As XDocument = XDocument.Load(SETTINGS_FILE_PATH)

' so processing 

 xdocSetting.Save(LEADS_FILE_PATH)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it finds node and overwrite that node and save that changes...

Below are the example...

```
Dim xdocSetting As XDocument = XDocument.Load(SETTINGS_FILE_PATH)
'After loading file it maches with downloaded enumerable'
Dim lS as IEnumerable(of XElement) = (your query)
XdocSetting.Save(SETTINGS_FILE_PATH)
```

Mean while it doing write operation, it locks file explicit.